# Identify client connected to OpenVPN server

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

### Current Setup

I am using a Raspberry Pi running some home automation stuff behind my router.
On the Raspberry Pi there is OpenVPN, which we use to connect from outside our LAN e.g. with a mobile phone.
We can reach the Raspberry Pi via forwarding the port for the VPN connection from the router.

### Desired Result

I am logging and analyzing successful and unsuccessful login attempts via the `/var/log/openvpn.log` file. For all the successful log-in attemps I would like to have a mechanism to identify the connected device (typically one out of a number of different Android mobile phones all using the same public/private key pair to connect) reliably.
However, the only info I get from the log-file is the public IP-address of the device, which cannot be linked to the individual phone.

Therefore I was wondering, if there is an easy way to achieve such an identification triggered from the VPN-Server side?
Ideally via one command on the terminal of the Raspberry Pi that would execute as soon as a new device was connected. Something along the lines of using `arp` in a LAN.
If needed it would be possible to also install additional app(s) on the Android devices.

### Current solution that should be replaced

As it stands I am doing this in a rather clumsy way at the moment with the Tasker app running on the Android phone that connects to an MQTT broker on the Raspberry Pi after opening the VPN connection. I would like to replace this method as it has several problems in terms of reliability and handling.

Comment: Just use a separate client certificate for each phone with a unique cn

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I was hoping to avoid using individual certificates, if possible.

Comment: Why? They are there to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @hardillb It may be far fetched, but assuming the private key is compromised or the VPN server has a security hole, I could detect with this method that a new (unwanted) device performed a login.